# Safari 13 Beta on Mac OS hanging when I click on a dropdown

Tags: macos, safari, dropdown, html-select

We have a situation that Safari 13 (Beta 2 for Mac OS X 10.14) hangs on our website when clicking on a dropdown. (An HTML select element).

We have a dropdown to select the (clothing) size on every product detail page, so our site is useless with this bug.

I first experienced this in Safari Technology Preview 92.

The problem does not occur on iOS 13 (luckily) on our site.
Other sites do not have the same problem.

Can other people confirm this bug?
Does anybody have a clue as to why this happens? How can we avoid this?

Comment: I can confirm that the bug still is present in Safari 13 that is recently rolled out to customers. Luckily we had the fix ready to apply on our site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our software partner found the problem. It occurs when the styling contains:
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

A solution for us is to (globally) override the styling of the select:

```
<style>
   select * {
       text-rendering: unset !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: I opened [an issue on the WebKit bug tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202055).

Comment: I did sent the bug report to Apple via the "report problem" when I force quit Safari. And sent a new one when I found the solution. I hope it makes the GM for Catalina.

Comment: Apparently not. We had to apply this fix via GTM now that Safari 13 is in the wild.

Comment: Had to go this fix globally, but it did correct the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing success with

```
<style>
  select {
    text-rendering: auto !important;
  }
</style>
```

after seeing [this comment](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2626#issuecomment-531515390) .

Answer (score 0):

This is also causing a few sites to become unresponsive for me, including WhatsApp Web. Removing rendering: optimizeLegibility; fixes the issue.

Comment: I can not reproduce this on WhatsApp Web with Safari 13. It looks like they countered this problem?